# Finding Wanderlust dependecy Emacs packages

Tags: emacs, wanderlust

I'm trying to install Wanderlust, but it needs other Emacs libraries.  Does anyone know where to find SEMI, APEL, and FLIM?  The [manual](http://www.gohome.org/wl/doc/wl_4.html#SEC4) says it should be on ftp://ftp.m17n.org/pub/mule/, but my DNS can't find ftp.m17n.org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site says:

> ftp.m17n.org is closed now. If you are
>   looking for something that was there,
>
> - It may be found at [http://unit.aist.go.jp/itri/itri-gist/ftp.m17n.org](http://unit.aist.go.jp/itri/itri-gist/ftp.m17n.org/).

ftp.jpl.org carries [APEL](ftp://ftp.jpl.org/pub/elisp/apel/), and you can grab [FLIM](http://www.kanji.zinbun.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~tomo/lemi/dist/flim/flim-1.14/) and [SEMI](http://www.kanji.zinbun.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~tomo/comp/emacsen/lisp/semi/semi-1.14-for-flim-1.14/) from kanji.zinbun.kyoto-u.ac.jp.

Comment: Whoa.  I didn't even see that comment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else finds this question now....

The canonical place to find Wanderlust and all its dependencies is [MELPA](https://melpa.org/) ([`https://melpa.org/`](https://melpa.org/))

Wanderlust development is now hosted on Github:

Source: https://github.com/wanderlust/wanderlust

Docs:  https://wanderlust.github.io/wl-docs/